# Why does push overwrite all contents of array in my object

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
    enum Gender {
      male = "M",
      female = "F",
    }
    // pet attributes
    interface petAttributes {
      age: number;
      name: string;
      gender: Gender;
    }
   // pet attributes acc to color
    interface petDetails {
      [color: string]: Array<petAttributes>;
    }
    // details and attributes acc to breed
    interface petType {
      [type: string]: petDetails;
    }
    // final dog record 
    let dogRecord: petType = {
      labrador: {
        black: [
          {
            age: 1,
            name: "bhalu",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "lily",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "",
            gender: Gender.female,
          }
        ],
        yellow: [
          {
            age: 1,
            name: "bhalu",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "lily",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
        ],
        chocolate: [
          {
            age: 1,
            name: "bhalu",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "lily",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
        ],
      },
      shitzu: {
        blackWhite: [
          {
            age: 1,
            name: "bhalu",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "lily",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
        ],
      },
      dalmation: {
        blackWhite: [
          {
            age: 1,
            name: "bhalu",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "lily",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
        ],
      },
      viszla: {
        brown: [
          {
            age: 1,
            name: "bhalu",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "lily",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
        ],
      },
      boxer: {
        brown: [
          {
            age: 1,
            name: "bhalu",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "lily",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
        ],
        mix: [
          {
            age: 1,
            name: "bhalu",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "lily",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
        ],
        white: [
          {
            age: 1,
            name: "bhalu",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "lily",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
        ],
      },
    };
    
    const updateRecord = ({
      type,
      breed,
      age,
      name,
      color,
      gender,
    }: any) => {
      if (type === allPets.dog) {
        for (const property in dogRecord) {
          if (breed === property) {
            let newPet: petAttributes = {
              age,
              name,
              gender,
            };
            console.log(dogRecord[property][color]);
            dogRecord[property][color].push(newPet);
          } else {
            dogRecord[breed] = {
              [color]: [
                {
                  age,
                  name,
                  gender,
                },
              ],
            };
          }
        }
      }
    };
    // update record with new dog of existing color
    updateRecord({
      type: allPets.dog,
      breed: "labrador",
      color: "black",
      age: 1,
      name: "rio",
      gender: Gender.female,
    });
```

The function updateRecord takes an object as an argument. This object is expected to have properties type, breed, age, name, color, and gender. The properties are destructured from the object in the function's parameter list.

The function starts with an if statement that checks if the type is equal to allPets.dog. This suggests that allPets is an object or enum containing various pet types, and dog is one of those types.

If the type is indeed dog, the function proceeds with a loop over properties of dogRecord. This loop seems to be iterating over different dog breeds.

Inside the loop, it checks if the breed matches the current property. If it does, it creates a new object newPet with properties age, name, and gender.

It then logs dogRecord[property][color] to the console. This indicates that it's trying to access a property within dogRecord using property as the breed and color as a property of that breed.

Comment: Where/how is `allPets` defined? Are you sure that the `===` comparison is working for the "type"?

Comment: it gets updated as {
  labrador: { black: [ [Object] ] },
  shitzu: {
    blackWhite: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    black: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    mix: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  dalmation: { blackWhite: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  viszla: { brown: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  boxer: {
    brown: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    mix: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    white: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
}

Comment: edit : enum AllPets {
  dog = "dog",
  cat = "cat",
  monkey = "monkey",
}

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `for` loop, just use direct property access as shown below. The reason it doesn't work is that the `for` loop iterates through all colors and creates new entries/overwrites existing entries inside the `else` part if the breed *differs* from the one the given pet has.

> **Note**
> I converted your typescript into JS to make it runnable as a stack
> snippet. Furthermore I shortened your `dogRecord` object to make the
> console output more readable.

```js
    const Gender = {
      female: 'F',
      male: 'M'
    };
    
    const allPets = {
      dog: 'dog',
      cat: 'cat',
      monkey: 'monkey'
    };
    
    // final dog record 
    let dogRecord = {
      labrador: {
        black: [
          {
            age: 1,
            name: "bhalu",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          // ... rest elided ...
        ],
        yellow: [
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "lily",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          // ... rest elided ...
        ],
        chocolate: [
          {
            age: 2,
            name: "",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          // ... rest elided ...
        ],
      },
      shitzu: {
        blackWhite: [
          {
            age: 1,
            name: "bhalu",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          // ... rest elided ...
        ],
      },
      dalmation: {
        blackWhite: [
          {
            age: 1,
            name: "bhalu",
            gender: Gender.female,
          },
          // ... rest elided ...
        ],
      },
      // ... rest elided ...
    };
    
    const updateRecord = ({
      type,
      breed,
      age,
      name,
      color,
      gender,
    }) => {
      if (type === allPets.dog) {
        let newPet = {
          age,
          name,
          gender,
        };
        if (dogRecord[breed]) { // does the breed exist?
          if (dogRecord[breed][color]) { // does the color exist?
            dogRecord[breed][color].push(newPet); // ... then add
          } else {
            dogRecord[breed][color] = [newPet]; // ... or create color entry
          }
        } else {
          dogRecord[breed] = {[color]: [newPet]}; // ... or create breed entry
        }
      }
    };
    
    console.log('dogRecord before', dogRecord);
    
    // update record with new dog of existing color
    updateRecord({
      type: allPets.dog,
      breed: "labrador",
      color: "black",
      age: 1,
      name: "rio",
      gender: Gender.female,
    });
    
    console.log('dogRecord after', dogRecord);
```